# Elasticsearch get data that were created the current week

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to write a range query that returns records that have timestamp in the current week (Sunday to Saturday). When I use the below query on a Sunday of current week, it returns data from previous week too.

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now/w",
        "lte": "now/w"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "gte": "now/d",
        "lte": "now/d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

In Elasticsearch a week is considered from Monday to Sunday

Answer (score -1):

I think you and now plus 7 days, right? My suggestion:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "gte": "now/d",
        "lte": "now+7d/d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```